# Minecraft not Executing

Tags: 12.04, java, games, minecraft, execute-command

So, I've had Ubuntu for a good 6 months on my HP Chromebook 14. I downloaded and began playing Minecraft immediately with no problem. Then, today I go onto my laptop and open up Ubuntu. I double click my Minecraft folder and it opens up the `.jar` like a folder. Its marked as being allowed to execute as a program. I didn't change anything, but I've been looking on forums and haven't found this happening to anyone else. I've re-installed Minecraft multiple times,tried manually opening it from the terminal and everything but nothing has worked. If I need to re-install Ubuntu I will, but if this is fixable please like me know!

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps and your problems are gone.

---

Install Oracle Java 8

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

---

Use the `minecraft-installer`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

Once installed, run Minecraft from the menu / Dash, login with your Minecraft account and the installation should start automatically.

<sub>[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/easily-install-minecraft-in-ubuntu-via.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the `openjdk` package.

1. Run `sudo apt-get remove openjdk-7-jre`

> If you don't have `openjdk` then skip to the last step
>
> **NOTE** - If you have a different version replace the `7` with the version number for  your version
>
> Run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`
>
> That should work.